# How to remove a wan connected datacenter in consul

Tags: consul

I have a completely failed datacenter cluster(DC1) which I'll not use in future. But it is wan-join ed with another live data cluster(DC2) which I'd like to continue using.

I've already marked all the members of DC1 as 'left' using `consul force-leave`

But I still see DC2 when I list the datacenters using `consul catalog datacenters`. How can I remove it?

In simpler words : How can we break wan connection between two consul clusters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These datacenters will be removed by consul in 72 hours.

Comment: Thanks for providing the answer to your own question. Helped me a lot